# Merge two database with a common key

Tags: dataset, associations

I have two list: in one of them the name of certain compounds, and in the other one the properties of each compounds.
So I want to merge them to have for each compound name the relative properties.
Imagine you have two list of data and you want merge them, in this way:

```
 compounds = {{"N", "Name", "CAS", "family", "subfamily"}, {1., "METHANE","74-82-8",
"n-Alkanes", ""}, {2., "ETHANE", "74-84-0", "N-ALKANES", ""}, {3.,
"PROPANE", "74-98-6", "N-ALKANES", ""}, {4., "ISOBUTANE", 
"75-28-5", "METHYLALKANES", "2-methylalkanes"}, {5., "n-BUTANE", 
"106-97-8", "N-ALKANES", ""}, {6., "1,1,3-TRIMETHYLCYCLOHEXANE", 
"3073-66-3", "Alkylcyclohexanes", ""}, {7., "n-PENTANE", 
"109-66-0", "N-ALKANES", ""}, {8., "ISOPENTANE", "78-78-4", 
"METHYLALKANES", "2-METHYLALKANES"}, {9., "NEOPENTANE", "463-82-1",
"Dimethylalkanes", "2,2-dimethylalkanes"}, {11., "n-HEXANE", 
"110-54-3", "N-ALKANES", ""}, {12., "2-METHYLPENTANE", "107-83-5", 
"METHYLALKANES", "2-METHYLALKANES"}, {13., "3-METHYLPENTANE", 
"96-14-0", "METHYLALKANES", "3-METHYLALKANES"}, {14., 
"2,2-DIMETHYLBUTANE", "75-83-2", "DIMETHYLALKANES", 
"2,2-DIMETHYLALKANES"}};

 properties = {{93.15, 0.000202, 3287., 1., "LVS", 25244., 
"Experimental", "< 25%", "R"}, {113.15, 0.000138, 3287., 1., 
"LVS", 25244., "Experimental", "< 25%", "R"}, {233.15, 0.000094, 
8798., 2., "LVS", 25233., "Experimental", "< 5%", "N"}, {253.15, 
0.000078, 8798., 2., "LVS", 25233., "Experimental", "< 5%", 
"N"}, {273.15, 0.00006, 8798., 2., "LVS", 25233., "Experimental", 
"< 5%", "N"}, {173.15, 0.00042, 13089., 3., "LVS", 25238., 
"Experimental", "< 10%", "N"}, {193.15, 0.00034, 13089., 3., 
"LVS", 25238., "Experimental", "< 10%", "N"}, {233.15, 0.00022, 
13089., 3., "LVS", 25238., "Experimental", "< 10%", "N"}, {273.15,
 0.000195, 13089., 3., "LVS", 25238., "Experimental", "< 10%", 
"N"}, {273.15, 0.000351, 32270., 12., "LVS", 25227., 
"Experimental", "< 3%", "A"}, {293.15, 0.000286, 32270., 12., 
"LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A"}, {313.15, 0.000237, 
32270., 12., "LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A"}, {273.75,
 0.000369, 32271., 12., "LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", 
"A"}, {278.15, 0.00035, 32271., 12., "LVS", 25227., 
"Experimental", "< 3%", "A"}, {283.15, 0.000332, 32271., 12., 
"LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A"}};
```

I want to merge the two list. When the program read 1. in the second list (properties) I want that he writes the name, the cas number, the family and subfamily.
At the end this is what I wish...

```
  whatIneed = {{93.15, 0.000202, 3287., "METHANE", "LVS", 25244., 
"Experimental", "< 25%", "R", "74-82-8", "n-Alkanes"}, {113.15, 
0.000138, 3287., "METHANE", "LVS", 25244., "Experimental", 
"< 25%", "R", "74-82-8", "n-Alkanes"}, {233.15, 0.000094, 8798., 
"ETHANE", "LVS", 25233., "Experimental", "< 5%", "N", "74-84-0", 
"N-ALKANES"}, {253.15, 0.000078, 8798., "ETHANE", "LVS", 25233., 
"Experimental", "< 5%", "N", "74-84-0", "N-ALKANES"}, {273.15, 
0.00006, 8798., "ETHANE", "LVS", 25233., "Experimental", "< 5%", 
"N", "74-84-0", "N-ALKANES"}, {173.15, 0.00042, 13089., "PROPANE",
 "LVS", 25238., "Experimental", "< 10%", "N", "74-98-6", 
"N-ALKANES"}, {193.15, 0.00034, 13089., "PROPANE", "LVS", 25238., 
"Experimental", "< 10%", "N", "74-98-6", "N-ALKANES"}, {233.15, 
0.00022, 13089., "PROPANE", "LVS", 25238., "Experimental", 
"< 10%", "N", "74-98-6", "N-ALKANES"}, {273.15, 0.000195, 13089., 
"PROPANE", "LVS", 25238., "Experimental", "< 10%", "N", "74-98-6",
 "N-ALKANES"}, {273.15, 0.000351, 32270., "2-METHYLPENTANE", 
"LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A", "107-83-5", 
"METHYLALKANES"}, {293.15, 0.000286, 32270., "2-METHYLPENTANE", 
"LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A"}, {313.15, 0.000237, 
32270., "2-METHYLPENTANE", "LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", 
"A", "107-83-5", "METHYLALKANES"}, {273.75, 0.000369, 32271., 
"2-METHYLPENTANE", "LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A", 
"107-83-5", "METHYLALKANES"}, {278.15, 0.00035, 32271., 
"2-METHYLPENTANE", "LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A", 
"107-83-5", "METHYLALKANES"}, {283.15, 0.000332, 32271., 
"2-METHYLPENTANE", "LVS", 25227., "Experimental", "< 3%", "A", 
"107-83-5", "METHYLALKANES"}};
```

I tried to solve my problem with this answer:
[Merging two lists with possible different keys](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66314/merging-two-lists-with-possible-different-keys).
But in my opinion there is an error in the Caitlin J. Ramsey (he explains in a clear way all the procedure) answer because he does not define the "values" variable, but with my score I can't write a comment. 
So here I'm.
Thanks.

Comment: `values` is `merged` in that answer, please have a try.

Comment: FYI you'd probably be better using `Association` or `Dataset` to handle this stuff, but here is a quick one liner which assumes all lists are in the correct order: `MapAt[# /. ((#[[1]] -> #[[2]]) & /@ 
     Rest@compounds) &, properties, {All, {4}}]` that will get your `whatIneed`. Also, you have a typo in `compounds`, the headers aren't separated from the first entry i.e. ` ..."subfamily", 1., "METHANE"...` should be `..."subfamily"},{1., "METHANE"...`

Comment: @N.J.Evans thanks a lot. This is a very nice way, but in this way I can't have also the other required values such as Cas, subfamily...and so on.

Comment: @ happy fish: yes it is right...Thanks!

Comment: @happyfish: As I said you're right, but this doesn't solve my problem. In fact in my second list (properties) I've repeated values, so that solution is not good for me. In fact in AssociationThread, "If any of the key are repeated, later instances replace earlier ones".

Comment: @GiorgyTisni OK, I will write a solution then. Before that I want to confirm one thing: is the number to replace in the second list __always__ on the `4th` position? If not, there is a problem if you have two `1`s (another one may be some other data that shouldn't be replaced)

Comment: Oh I missed the other fields, does this work? `MapAt[# /. ((#[[1]] -> Sequence @@ (#[[2;;-2]])) & /@ 
     Rest@compounds) &, properties, {All, {4}}]`

Answer (score 7):

You may use [`JoinAcross`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JoinAcross.html) with [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) or [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html).  I show with `Dataset` below. To perform with `Association` remove the [`Postfix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html) and `Dataset` from `dsCompounds` and `dsProperties`.  Also, you may find the [`ChemicalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChemicalData.html) and [`ElementData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ElementData.html) functions of interest.

```
dsCompounds = 
 AssociationThread[First@compounds, #] & /@ Rest@compounds // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dsProperties = 
 AssociationThread[
     Insert["N", 4]@Table["P" <> ToString@i, {i, 8}], #] & /@ properties // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then use `JoinAcross` on [`Key`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html) `"N"`

```
JoinAcross[dsProperties, dsCompounds, "N"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your replacement keys are at the `4th` position, for the reason above in the comment. If you continue to work with lists,

```
asso = Association[Rest@compounds /. {key_?NumericQ, rest___} :> (key -> List@rest)];
f[{pre : Repeated[_, {3}], key_, rest___}] := Join[{pre, rest}, asso[key]];
f /@ properties
```

Comment: now it works perfectly...