# Creating a new list from other two lists using for loops

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists 'ups' and 'downs' where they are composed of positions of an element in a matrix and their weight. For example,

```
ups = {{{x1,y1},wu1},{{x2,y2},wu2},...}
downs = {{{X1,Y1},wd1},{{X2,Y2},wd2},...}
```

Now, I want to create a new list called 'full' where it contains both of these information. I want to do the following:

1. If `{x1,y1}=={X1,Y1}`, then

   ```
   full = {{{x1,y1},wu1,wd1}}...}
   ```
2. Otherwise,

   ```
   full = {{{x1,y1},wu1,0},{{X1,Y1},0,wd1},...}
   ```

Here is what I tried:

```
For[j = 1, j <= Length[downs], j++,
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[ups], i++,
      If[ups[[i]][[1]] == downs[[j]][[1]], 
       AppendTo[listFull, {ups[[i]], downs[j][[2]]}], 
       AppendTo[
        AppendTo[listFull, {ups[[i]], 0}], {downs[[j]][[1]], 0, 
          downs[[j]][[2]]}]];
      i = i++;]
     j = j++;]]
```

Applying `AppendTo` twice seems to cause trouble.. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide minimal example and expected result.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Related: [(60069)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60069/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should be versatile and reasonably efficient:

```
join[lists_, pad_: 0] :=
  With[{
    rules = AssociationThread @@@ Transpose /@ lists,
    keys = Union @@ lists[[All, All, 1]]
   },
   Join[keys ~Partition~ 1, Lookup[rules, keys, pad]\[Transpose], 2]
  ]
```

Examples:

```
join[{ups, dws}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, u1, d1}, {{1, 2}, u2, 0}, {{2, 3}, 0, d2}}
> ```

```
{
 {{"d", 5}, {"a", 1}, {"b", 4}},
 {{"f", 8}, {"c", 5}, {"d", 1}},
 {{"c", 4}, {"e", 1}, {"d", 6}},
 {{"b", 8}, {"d", 6}, {"e", 7}},
 {{"f", 6}, {"c", 5}, {"e", 5}}
} // join
```

> ```
> {{"a", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>  {"b", 4, 0, 0, 8, 0},
>  {"c", 0, 5, 4, 0, 5},
>  {"d", 5, 1, 6, 6, 0},
>  {"e", 0, 0, 1, 7, 5},
>  {"f", 0, 8, 0, 0, 6}}
> ```

Padding can be controlled via the second parameter:

```
join[{ups, dws}, "foo"]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, u1, d1}, {{1, 2}, u2, "foo"}, {{2, 3}, "foo", d2}}
> ```

Comment: I am glad I was in right direction...I really like the clarity and imho elegance +1:)

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks.  Unfortunately I think I lost some clarity with the edit but I gained a large measure of performance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Since I'm holding off re-installing 10.x until a non foo-bar release, how does the performance of this compare to the `MapThread` implementation of *Pickett* (which can be ~doubled with pre-10 functionality)?

Comment: @rasher I don't believe Pickett's answer is general; does it not rely on an incidental quality of the example data?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Not sure I follow - error aside (should be using `Sequence` to properly string mismatches vs `Flatten`), it seems to do what OP is after (the x1/X1... seems to imply positional comparisons). Am I missing something? Nonetheless, curious re: perf. comparison. Oh, and +1 for your usual elegance.

Comment: @rasher Okay, I can see that interpretation now.  Surely this is far more complicated than his then, but give me code you want me to use for the comparison and I'll run it.

Answer (score 4):

A different solution:

```
ups = {{{1, 1}, u1}, {{1, 2}, u2}};
dws = {{{1, 1}, d1}, {{2, 3}, d2}};

f[{a_, v1_}, {a_, v2_}] := {{a, v1, v2}}
f[{a_, v1_}, {b_, v2_}] := {{a, v1, 0}, {b, 0, v2}}

Join @@ MapThread[f, {ups, dws}]
```

> `{{1, 1}, u1, d1, {{1, 2}, u2, 0}, {{2, 3}, 0, d2}}`

Functions in Mathematica are really replacement rules. Therefore this solution can also be implemented with rules.

```
rules = {
   {{a_, v1_}, {a_, v2_}} :> {{a, v1, v2}},
   {{a_, v1_}, {b_, v2_}} :> {{a, v1, 0}, {b, 0, v2}}
   };

Join @@ MapThread[{##} /. rules &, {ups, dws}]
```

> `{{1, 1}, u1, d1, {{1, 2}, u2, 0}, {{2, 3}, 0, d2}}`

Comment: `Join @@ MapThread[f, {ups, dws}]` is shorter; +1.

Comment: Oh, I think you want: `f[{a_, v1_}, {a_, v2_}] := {{a, v1, v2}}` (extra brackets).  Hm... I just realized that this is fragile; it probably does not work in many cases because I believe it relies on an incidental alignment of the two lists.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think the alignment is incidental, or at least that's not how I interpreted it.

Comment: Yes, I see that interpretation now as I commented to rasher.  You've still got my vote.

Answer (score 2):

```
ups = {{{1, 1}, u1}, {{1, 2}, u2}};
dws = {{{1, 1}, d1}, {{2, 3}, d2}};

dim = Max[ups[[All, 1]], dws[[All, 1]]]
su = SparseArray[Rule @@@ #, {dim, dim}] & /@ {ups, dws}
Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2, Sequence @@ #1} &, MapThread[List, su, 2], {2}], 1]

(*
 {{{1, 1}, u1, d1}, {{1, 2}, u2, 0}, {{1, 3}, 0, 0}, 
  {{2, 1}, 0,   0}, {{2, 2}, 0,  0}, {{2, 3}, 0, d2}, 
  {{3, 1}, 0,   0}, {{3, 2}, 0,  0}, {{3, 3}, 0, 0}}

*)
```

Comment: Thank you, belisarius! One more question though, what can I do to just have non-zero weight elements in the list? i.e. {{1, 3},0, 0} is not needed.

Comment: @user27430 See the docs for `ReplaceAll[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

For something else:

```
ups = {{{1, 1}, u1}, {{1, 2}, u2}};
dws = {{{1, 1}, d1}, {{2, 3}, d2}};
```

then,

```
Module[{
  rl = Thread[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}} -> CharacterRange["a", "c"]], 
  a1, a2, ku, ds, an},
 a1 = Association[Rule[#1 /. rl, #2] & @@@ ups]; 
 a2 = Association[Rule[#1 /. rl, #2] & @@@ dws];
 ku = KeyUnion[{a1, a2}];
 ds = Dataset[ku];
 an = ({#, Normal[ds[All, #]]} & /@ {"a", "b", "c"} /. 
     Missing[__] :> 0) /. (Reverse /@ rl);
 {#1, Sequence @@ #2} & @@@ an
 ]
```

yields:

```
{{{1, 1}, u1, d1}, {{1, 2}, u2, 0}, {{2, 3}, 0, d2}}
```